# Can you access the iPhone's address book in a Dashcode-designed web application?

Tags: iphone, dashcode

I'm writing a web application using Dashcode.  Is it possible to access the iPhone address book from within this web application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dashcode is just the development environment IDE for generating widgets and iPhone apps and actually write the apps using JavaScript, HTML and CSS. Any app you make will need to sit on a server and be accessed through the mobile browser on the iPhone. So the question is can you/i connect from a web app to the iPhone native applications. Just from a security point of view i would doubt that this is possible or even desirable, 
However i have seen suggestions that a native application in x-code could be built that would have a web interface that would be able to talk to the browser but i am not sure how you would engineer that or if it would work.
I suspect a simple solution is to sync your iPh=one contact with Gmail, or similar web app and then access it or write your own server that you sync contacts to. However this is not a general solution i suspect.

Hope this helps even though it is not the answer.